# C++ Reading from several sections of a file is too slow

Tags: c++, optimization

I need to read byte arrays from several locations of a big file.
I have already optimized the file so that as few sections as possible have to be read, and the sections are as closely together as possible.

I have 20 calls like this one:

```
m_content.resize(iByteCount);

fseek(iReadFile,iStartPos ,SEEK_SET);
size_t readElements = fread(&m_content[0], sizeof(unsigned char), iByteCount, iReadFile);
```

iByteCount is around 5000 on average.

Before using fread, I used a memory-mapped file, but the results were approximately the same.

My calls are still too slow (around 200 ms) when called for the first time. When I repeat the same call with the same sections of bytes to read, it is very fast (around 1 ms), but that does not really help me.

The file is big (around 200 mb).
After this call, I have to read double values from a different section of the file, but I can not avoid this.

I don't want to split it up in 2 files. I have seen the "huge file approach" used by other people, too, and they overcame this problem somehow.

If I use memory-mapping, the first call of reading is always slow. If I then repeat reading from this section, it is lightening fast. When I then read from a different section, it is slow for the first time, but then lightening fast the second time.

I have no idea why this is so.

Does anybody have any more ideas for me?
Thank you.

Comment: I know this might be impractical, but if you can, try putting your file in an SSD drive. Maybe your HDD's seek time is the one slowing you down.

Comment: My drives are fine, and SSDs are not an option for me.

Comment: One end of the spectrum could be read the entire file into memory, if you can afford it.

Comment: I did that, it made no difference.

Comment: After the initial read of the whole file any access to the data should be nearly instant.  Is it the original loading time you object to?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about memory-mapping. No, reading the entire file (200 mb) into memory is not an option.

Comment: I don't see how we can help you with this issue.  You cannot read from a file any quicker (there is no magic flag to say "read faster").  There is either an issue with your hardware or 200mS is how long it is supposed to take.

Comment: Do you have a network access ? Accessing to a memcached would be around the millisecond assuming the cache is preloaded.

Comment: There is no network access.

Comment: The reading is ultra fast once I read some sections and then repeat just the very same call. The first call is around 200 ms, the second call is like 5 ms.

Comment: How are you opening the file?

Comment: @TAS I use  iReadFile = _wfopen(sPath.c_str(),L"rb"); or CreateFileMapping( hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL );. Does not make a difference for me in aspects of speed.

Comment: If you only need to read parts of the file the best you can hope for is lowering the amortized cost.  If you can arrange for the data to be sequential, do so.  If not, arrange your reads so you are always seeking forward in the file and hope the disk cache gives you some help if they are not spread too far apart.

Comment: There are several "sections" in my 200 mb file. I need to read from each of the sections. Each section is ordered in such a way that there is not much hopping around, but only forward reading is not possible. It is like call to section A, call to section A, call to section A, call to section B, call to section B, call to section B, call to section A, call to section A, call to section A, call to section C.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Should I do 3 memory mappings to the file so that I can handle each call to one of the 3 sections using a different map? :-)

Comment: Did you think about loading in memory each section at once ? First call in A, load A, then answer calls. then unload A. of course it is interesting or not depending of the size of your "section".

Comment: ok I just see now your last comment. 3 sections is not enough to do some sort of pagination.

Comment: Do you run it in Debug mode?

Comment: I am testing it in Release mode.

Comment: Did you run the executable from console instead of IDE?

Comment: Yes, I did. The Release mode is much faster than the Debug mode.

Comment: @trojanfoe Perhaps you should make your reply the answer. I use my primary disk now, and the delay has gone...

Comment: OK, I've added it as an answer.

Comment: Is compression still an option? Did you profile? Is RAM handling a problem too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(moved to an answer as requested by the OP)*

You cannot read from a file any quicker (there is no magic flag to say "read faster"). There is either an issue with your hardware or 200mS is how long it is supposed to take

Answer (score 6):

Disk drives have two (actually three) factors that limit their speed: access time, sequential bandwidth, and bus latency/bandwidth.

What you feel most is access time. Access time is typically in the millisecond ballpark. Having to do a seek takes upwards of 5 (often more than 10) milliseconds on a typical harddisk. Note that the number printed on a disk drive is the "average" time, not the worst time (and, in some cases it seems that it's much closer to "best" than "average").

Sequential read bandwidth is typically upwards of 60-80 MiB/s even for a slow disk, and 120-150 MiB/s for a faster disk (or >400MiB on solid state). Bus bandwidth and latency are something you usually don't care about as bus speed usually exceeds the drive speed (except if you use a modern solid state disk on SATA-2, or a 15k harddisk on SATA-1, or any disk over USB).

Also note that you cannot change the drive's bandwidth, nor the bus bandwidth. Nor can you change the seek time. However, you **can** change the **number** of seeks.

In practice, this means you must *avoid seeks as much as you can*. If that means reading in data that you do not need, do not be afraid of doing so. It is **much** faster to read 100 kiB than to read 5 kiB, seek ahead 90 kilobytes, and read another 5 kiB.

If you can, read the whole file in one go, and only use the parts you are interested in. 200 MiB should not be a big hindrance on a modern computer. Reading in 200 MiB with `fread` into an allocated buffer might however be forbidding (that depends on your target architecture, and what else your program is doing). But don't worry, you have already had the best solution to the problem: memory mapping.
While memory mapping is not a "magic accelerator", it is nevertheless as close to "magic" as you can get.

The big advantage of memory mapping is that you can directly read from the buffer cache. Which means that the OS will prefetch pages, and you can even ask it to more aggressively prefetch, so effectively all your reads will be "instantaneous". Also, what is stored in the buffer cache is in some sense "free".
Unluckily, memory mapping is not always easy to get right (especially since the documentation and the hint flags typically supplied by operating systems are deceptive or counter-productive).

While you have no guarantee that what has been read once stays in the buffers, in practice this is the case for anyting of "reasonable" size. Of course the operating system cannot and will not keep a terabyte of data in RAM, but something around 200 MiB will quite reliably stay in the buffers on a "normal" modern computer. Reading from buffers works more or less in zero time.
So, your goal is to get the operating system to read the file into its buffers, as sequentially as possible. Unless the machine runs out of physical memory so it is forced to discard buffer pages, this will be lightning fast (and if that happens, every other solution will be equally slow).

Linux has the [readahead](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) syscall which lets you prefetch data. Unluckily, it blocks until data has been fetched, which is not what you probably want (you would thus have to use an extra thread for this). `madvise(MADV_WILLNEED)` is a less reliable, but probably better alternative. `posix_fadvise` may work too, but note that Linux limits the readahead to twice the default readahead size (i.e. 256kiB).
Do not have yourself being fooled by the docs, as the docs are deceptive. It may seem that `MADV_RANDOM` is a better choice, as your access is "random". It makes sense to be honest to the OS about what you're doing, doesn't it? Usually yes, but not here. *This, simply turns off prefetching*, which is the exact opposite of what you really want. I don't know the rationale behind this, maybe some ill-advised attempt to converve memory -- in any case it is detrimental to your performance.

Windows (since Windows 8, for desktop only) has [PrefetchVirtualMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh780543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which does exactly what one would want here, but unluckily it's only available on the newest version. On older versions, there is just... nothing.

A very easy, efficient, *and portable* way of populating the pages in your mapping is to launch a worker thread that faults every page. This sounds horrendous, but it works very nicely, and is operating-system agnostic.
Something like `volatile int x = 0; for(int i = 0; i < len; i += 4096) x += map[i];` is entirely sufficient. I am using such code to pre-fault pages prior to accessing them, it works at speeds unrivalled to any other method of populating buffers and uses very little CPU.

Comment: enlightening answer

Answer (score 1):

1) The difference in access speed between your first read and subsequent ones is perfectly understandable : your first call actually read the file from the disk, and [this takes time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics). However your kernel (not mentioning the disk controller) keep the accessed data buffered so when you access it a second time it is a pure memory access (1ms).
Even if you only need to access really tiny portions of the file, libc/kernel/controller optimizations access the disk in quite large chunk. You can read the libc/OS/controller doc to try and align your reads on these chunks.

2) You're using stream input, try using direct `open`/`read`/`close` functions : low-level I/O have less overhead (obviously). Nothing gets faster than this, so if you still find this too slow, you have an OS or hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

as it look you have a good benchmark, try to switch the size and the count in your fread call. reading 1 times 1000 bytes will be faster than 1000 x 1 byte.

Comment: This is not possible. I have already ordered the data nicely so that I have as few freads as possible.

Comment: Excuse me, but I was not talking about the number of fread but about how you call it. fread as 2 arguments the size of the elements you read and the count of element. I'm not sure but if you switch those two arguments it may lead to a small optimization.

Comment: That did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Disk is slow, and as you pointed out, the delay comes from the first access - that's the disk spinning up and accessing the sectors necessary. You're always going to pay that cost one time.

You could improve your performance a little by using memory mapped IO. See either [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) (Linux) or [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)+[MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows).

Comment: I already used memory-mapping, it gave approximately the same results as the fread. I will update my problem description to make it more clear.

Comment: Approximately the same results is roughly what I'd expect unless you were transfering large amounts of data -- memory-mapping mostly allows you to save memory pressure and bandwidth by letting you access the data directly rather the OSes disk cache rather than forcing you to duplicate it to someplace else for access. If you're dealing with a very small amount of data, the impact will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

> I have already optimized the file so that as few sections as possible have to be read

Correct me if I'm wrong, but in reference to the file being optimised, I'm assuming you mean you've ordered the sections to minimize the number of reads that take place and not what I'm going to suggest.

Being bound by IO here is likely due to the seek times, so other than getting a faster storage medium, your options are limited.

Two possible ideas I had are: -

1) Compress the data that is stored, which may give you slightly faster read times, but will still not help with seek time. You'd have to test if this benefits at all.

2) If relevant, as soon as you've retrieved one block of data, move it to a thread and start processing it while another read takes place. You may be doing this already, but if not, I thought it worth mentioning.